# JavaScript computation bug

Tags: javascript, math

I'm using Chrome, version 37.0.2062.124 m, and FireFox 22.0 and the computation gives me wrong result:

```
5*0.1 //the result is 0.5
6*0.1 //the result is 0.6000000000000001, it should be 0.6
7*0.1 //0.7000000000000001
8*0.1 //0.8
```

If possible to answer, how did they come up with this? If not, is there any library that does the job? I don't need new data type, `float` is enough, I just want this to get the correct result.

Comment: If you are truly in need of calculations with high precision, see: http://blog.smartbear.com/testing/four-serious-math-libraries-for-javascript/

Comment: A common work-around is to round to a certain number of decimal points of accuracy when displaying the result and the tiny discrepancy will go away.

Comment: You need to read What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating Point Numbers.  You should also know that it's not a language or library flaw.  You can no more represent 0.1 exactly in binary than you can 1/3 in decimal.